# Python multiprocessing on windows, figures get stuck

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I hope you can help me. I do this work in Canopy under Windows 7. I am trying to do some data processing with many data sets. In the main program I do visualization and some differencing. Now when I add a multiprocessing pool at the end, in execution, it starts to plot and difference in every process. Forcing to close the figures does not help. I created a dummy example that does the same. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import pylab as p

def cube(x,y):
    return y*x**3

cxrange = range(1,7)
cyrange = range(4,8)
p.figure()
p.hold()
p.plot(cxrange, label='x')
p.plot(cxrange,'k:', label='y')
p.hold(False)
p.show()

for y in cyrange:
    if __name__ == '__main__':    
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
        results = [pool.apply(cube, args=(x,y)) for x in cxrange]
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print(results)
```

Comment: You should create the pool outside of the for loop. You also probably want to use `apply_async` instead of `apply`, otherwise you're just running `cube` sequentially on each element, rather than doing it in concurrently.